# How to create a method that returns an ArrayList

Tags: java

From reading tutorials and practicing Java, I have come across a problem. I have created a String ArrayList, added string to it. However I want one method which allows me to add more string to this arrayList and another method which allows me to display this arrayList. below is my attempt to solve this problem. My code only prints an empty Array List

```
class apples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        viewArrayList(); //prints a empty arraylist
    }

    public static void addString() {
        ArrayList<String> destinationArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        destinationArray.add("example1");
        destinationArray.add("example2");
    }

    static ArrayList GetArrayList() {
        ArrayList<String> destinationArray = new ArrayList<String>();

        return destinationArray;
    }

    public static void viewArrayList() {
        System.out.println(GetArrayList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are trying to manipulate the same list repeatedly, you would be much better served by creating a `List<String>` property in your class, initializing it in your constructor, then create methods to manipulate it (add items, remove items, return the list etc). You should also remove the static modifier that you've sprinkled throughout your code.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Object of a `ArrayList` and pass reference to different methods. Example create a `ArrayList` Object in main class and pass it to `addString` & `display` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<String> destinationArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    viewArrayList(destinationArray); 
    displayArrayList(destinationArray);//prints a empty arraylist
}
public static void addString(List destinationArray ){   
    destinationArray.add("example1");
    destinationArray.add("example2");
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Didn't you forget adding addString() to getArrayList()?

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `destinationArray` is declared in a method, it meens that it only exists inside this method outside `addString()` the object does not exist anymore and you can't access it in other methods. To do it you have to declare it as a class variable like that :

```
class apples{
ArrayList<String> destinationArray = new ArrayList<String>();
public static void main(String[] args)
```

When your program is executed, in fact it executes the main method, as a result if you want to execute your method `addString()` you will have to call it in the main function. It will look like that :

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    this.addString();
    this.viewArrayList(); //prints a empty arraylist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
class apples
{
  private ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

  public void addString(String addString)
  {   
    this.array.add(addString);
  }


  public ArrayList<String> GetArrayList()
  {
    return array;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you use a different array list for each method.  Every time you use the keyword `new` you are creating a new (and empty) list.

At the top of your class create the ArrayList once...

```
private ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

then refer to myList in all your other methods without assigning it a new value.

```
public ArrayList<String> getArrayList() {
  return myList;
}

public void addSomeStrings() {
  myList.add("Some String");
  myList.add("Some Other String");
}
```

and don't be afraid to walk through a Java tutorial.  This is a fundamental concept and you may get pretty frustrated if you don't shore up your foundation.

Answer (score 0):

Compile and run following program.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Apples {
    static ArrayList<String> destinationArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("First time");
        viewArrayList();
        addString("Example1");
        addString("Example2");
        addString("Example3");

        System.out.print("Second time");
        viewArrayList();
        addString("Example4");
        addString("Example5");
        System.out.print("Third time");
        viewArrayList();
    }

    public static void addString(String example) {
        destinationArray.add(example);
    }

    static ArrayList getArrayList() {
        return destinationArray;
    }

    public static void viewArrayList() {
        System.out.println(getArrayList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the array object is the problem here. You are adding string to 1 array and trying to print another array. Remove the static block and the array declaration in addString(). Declare the array next to the class definition like this,

class apples {
ArrayList destinationArray = new ArrayList();
.. ....

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
public class Apples {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    viewArrayList(); //prints a empty arraylist
}

public static ArrayList<String> addString() {
    ArrayList<String> destinationArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    destinationArray.add("example1");
    destinationArray.add("example2");
    return destinationArray;
}

public static ArrayList<String> GetArrayList() {
    return addString();     
}

public static void viewArrayList() {
    System.out.println(GetArrayList());
}
```

}

Output:

[example1, example2]